# Giving an inductive definition of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}\text{ (real numbers).}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

What does it mean by "Give an inductive definition of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}\text{ (real numbers).}$"? I don't even know where to start, since I don't even understand what is being asked. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you're meant to relate $\prod^n$ to $\prod^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, how to compute prod(n,x) given prod(n-1,x).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just updated the question to reflect what the problem says verbatim.

Comment: I still think you're meant to relate $\prod^n$ to $\prod^{n-1}$.

Comment: Any thoguhts on the answer I posted a day ago, IVLIVS?

Comment: Earth to IVLIVS, come in, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The answer my prof. was looking for was this: $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x^{2}_{i}=x^{2}_{1}\cdot x^{2}_{2}\cdot ...\cdot x^{2}_{n}.$ Hence, \begin{align}a_{1}&=x^{2}_{1}\\ a_{n+1}&=a_{n}\cdot x^{2}_{n+1}\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it to mean the following. For $n=1,2,\dots$, let $a_n$ stand for $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^2$. Find a formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ (and, if necessary, $a_{n-2},a_{n-3},\dots$).